# How to format the OS X installer USB stick that comes with MacBook Air?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, disk-format

When you purchase a new MacBook Air they give you a mini-USB drive that is used to reinstall OS X and iLife '11.

How can I format this USB stick and put whatever I want on it?

The option to format is not available in Disc Utility and the USB stick mounts as a CD.

Note: I realize what the disk is used for and what Apple says on their FAQ. My question isn't "What do you think about formatting the USB?" it is "How can I format the USB?" The answer may be that it is impossible.

Comment: what about the option to erase? is that there?  I also remember reading about a command for putting a disk back into it's "factory" state, meaning you'd have to "initialize" the disk again.  I can't remember what it was called, but maybe "de-initialize disk mac os x" might be some keywords to start with.

Comment: @calavera - if it's read-only (see my answer below), there is no option to erase.

Answer (score 24):

From Apple's [MacBook Air: Frequently Asked Questions about Software Reinstall Drive](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4399):

> **Note**: The MacBook Air Software Reinstall Drive is read only.  You cannot erase it, reformat it, or reuse it as a general purpose USB storage device.

Honestly, thumb drives are dirt cheap these days—why would you want to lose your only way to reinstall your OS?

Comment: /agree "How do I reformat my restore DVDs so I can save what I want on them?" -- Are you crazy?

Comment: I don't have a macbook air, but I do have the cool little usb stick. I want to use it for other files. I realize that it's hard to format it (I tried), but I want to know how.

Comment: The Readonly could *maybe* be bypassed if you manage to open it, but that will probably break it anyway so I’d say you save it as a keyring :)

Comment: If it's emulating a CD drive, there are **lots** of reasons reformatting it is desirable. A thumbdrive which shows up as a hardware CD drive is great for installing OSes on all the computers which can't use bootable usb hard drives, but support USB CD drives (LOTS of early netbooks).

Comment: After the release of the first MacBook Air OS X could boot from a USB drive and FireWire drive.  I believe if a USB drive is formatted with a GUID partition and has an 10.5 install on it, it is bootable from it.

Comment: @Jonathan Mayhak: "I don't have an MacBook Air" - why do you have the USB installer stick for one, then? Shouldn't it be kept with the MacBook Air it shipped with?

Comment: Fake Name: The problem is the CD emulation is just in software. What's really going on is that it's a Flash ROM in hardware, which the software exposes as a CD drive for simplicity's sake. It also doesn't show up as a CD drive at the BIOS, only in an OS.

Comment: @VxJasonxV - There *are* some thumbdrives which show up as CD drive in the BIOS, notably the sandisk cruzer U3 series. I've used mine to install ubuntu on a laptop which didn't support booting off a normal thumbdrive, so it is very useful, in specific situations.

Comment: Interesting. All my experience comes from Cruzers with the U3 technology too, but last I knew it was all read-only and couldn't be changed.

Comment: I think it's obvious why you'd want to re-use it. It's nice and small and fits readily onto a keyring.

You can always re-install OS X via a usb dvd drive or dvd sharing if required so there's no problem there.

Comment: It is obviously flash ROM because it's cheaper to manufacture than RAM and would have no capability to write to it after it's been burned.

Answer (score 0):

It most definitely is possible to reformat these drives and they are awesome 8GB USB ThumbDrives, once you do. However, I did it by accident, playing with the partition tables in Mac OS X Terminal (Command Line) and haven't replicated the process yet.

If this sounds too good to be true, check out this little video, I just posted to YouTube: [MacBook Air Software Reinstall Drive - HACKED](https://youtu.be/CnlL4MJsfcA)